# D: are global variables bad?

Tags: d

Sometimes I need to get variable variable, that can be accessed from any place of code. But I often hear that global variables are bad. What is the best practice in D for such case?

Now my code look like:

```
string roothtml;
static this()
{
    roothtml = buildPath(getcwd, "html");
}

void main()
{
//
}
```

Is it's good or bad practice?

Comment: I think there is an exception in every language. Settings are often stored in "global" variables. It's best to keep global variables read only if possible, though.

Comment: Usually they're bad, because you do not have proper control about when and where they get accessed from. However D can counter-attack that with properties.

Comment: @Milie, Bauss thanks, but could you look at my source example in comment below (after rcorre answer). Maybe you can suggest me something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are global variables bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you really mean by 'global'. In the example above, I'd say its fine.
You appear to be showing a `main` module, which probably shouldn't be imported
by anything. In other words, it isn't really *global*, it is local to the main
module. It really isn't so different from

```
class Main {
  private string _roothtml;
  static this() { _roothtml = buildPath(getcwd, "html"); }
  void run() { }
}
```

Even if it isn't really your `main`, D's
[`module`](http://dlang.org/spec/module.html) system offers protections of its
own. Just stick a `private` on `roothtml` to encapsulate it within the module
(it wouldn't hurt to do this in your main module anyways, just to be clear).

A pattern like this is widely employed in the source code of git. Rather than
having a single main module that invokes a function for a given command, you
have many `main` functions -- one for each top-level command.

For example, take a look at
[`upload-pack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/upload-pack.c#L34-L54).

See those variables declared at the top of the source file?
Would the code have been any clearer or safer if they were wrapped in a class in
typical OOP style or of explicitly passed to each function in a more purely
functional style?

Each source file acts as a unit of encapsulation for a given command. This style is not always appropriate, but in the case of a program that can be thought of as a set of distinct commands, it can be cleaner than the alternatives.

Ultimately, the answer will be specific to the context, your given project, and
your personal style. Generally speaking, cross-module globals are something to
be looked on with suspicion, but module-level variables can sometimes be cleaner
than the alternatives.

Comment: could you help me in next example:
http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?z6jzf0xluqu0
I can't undserstand how to check if user is admin. On line 93 I am trying write if user is admin or not. But setting this variable I am doing at 280 line, and declaration in main (line 50).

In this case what would be best solution?

Comment: `static this` -> `this`. Yours isn't appreciably better because it's not offering any hooks for a test to inject state and because the value is effectively immutable. Change those and you get a more complex but more testable (and more safely testable) solution. The complexity may not be justified in some situations.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting the class as an alternative, I was trying to show that a module actually offers class-like encapsulation of its own. Now that I look back at my answer its admittedly a bit confusing...

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are problematic for a few reasons.

- It's harder to track where variables are coming from when you're reading. This makes it harder to understand a function using globals.
- It's harder to track where a variable is used. This makes it harder to modify how your global variables should be used.
- It's more awkward to inject test data and test stubs.
- Test state will spill over to other tests.
- `__gshared` globals require locking or immutability.
- Thread-local globals are thread-local, so you can't propagate writes to all threads.
- Any globals require you to think about whether you want it thread-local or `__gshared`.
- If you need to convert your single-tenant application into a multi-tenant one, that will be painful if you're using global variables. And it's more common than you probably suspect.
- You have to be careful not to build with `-unittest` when running your application so you don't trash global state initialized in a static constructor.

On the plus side, it's convenient that you don't have to pass global state everywhere. You don't have to use method to method object refactorings as often. You don't have to bring in a dependency injection system. It's very convenient when it's not biting you.